# Java set private attribute on static method outside

Tags: java

I just noticed something that doesn't make sense for me.

Take the following code:

```
public class User {
    private String name = "";

    public User() {}

    public static User fromJson(JSONObject json) {
        User user = new User();

        user.name = json.optString("name", "");
        System.out.println("Name = " + user.getName());
        // Will print: "Name = THEGIVENNAME"

        return user;
    }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public String setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

If I try to access the method `User.fromJson` outside the package of `User`, when I execute `user.getName()` it returns an empty String:

```
public void someMethod() {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {
        json.put("name", "Test Name");
    } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStacktrace(); }

    User user = User.fromJson(json);

    System.out.println("Name = " + user.getName());
    // Will print: "Name = "
}
```

But, if on the `User.fromJson` method I use `user.setName()` instead of `user.name =`, it works:

```
    ...
    public static User fromJson(JSONObject json) {
        User user = new User();

        user.setName(json.optString("name", ""));

        return user;
    }
    ...
```

And then:

```
public void someMethod() {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {
        json.put("name", "Test Name");
    } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStacktrace(); }

    User user = User.fromJson(json);

    System.out.println("Name = " + user.getName());
    // Will print: "Name = Test Name"
}
```

Is there something that I'm missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: Does the print inside the fromJson method print out the correct value in both cases?

Comment: Have you tried to debug?

Comment: I ran it and it gave me the correct results in both cases.. is this some kind of a bug with your version of the JVM(unlikely) or are you making some mistake compiling and executing it ? Don't know..

Comment: I'm using Android Studio to run.

Comment: Try after changing private String name = ""; to private static String name = "";

Comment: You do not provide the right code for what you describe: class `User` can't be compiled as is, because your setName() doesn't return a String as its declaration says it should. Changing it to `public void setName(String name)` (notice **void**) is the right way for a setter, and `User` now compiles. Idem for your first `someMethod` : its catch block should `e.printStackTrace()' with a **capital T**. With those two fixes to your sample code, it prints "_Name = Test Name_" as it should, as mentioned by @Pradyumna ... Either provide code to reproduce your error case, or be  this question deleted.